# Impossible to get ContentResolver.openInputStream(Uri uri) in the app with targetSdk 29 and compileSdk 29 on the device with API 29

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, android-10.0, android-9.0-pie, scoped-storage

I have two apps running on **Android 10 (API 29)** device. From the first app ("sender") I send a picture `uri` of a `jpg` file placed on the phone file system:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);        
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); 
String mimeType = AppUtils.getFileMimeType(uri, context);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg");
if (intent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null)
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open with"));
```

In the second app ("receiver") I try to open `InputStream` from above `uri`:

```
context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

and get this exception as a result:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider uri content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AMovies%2FNew/document/primary%3AMovies%2FNew%2FPanorama.jpg from pid=30753, uid=10487 requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2071)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:188)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:151)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:705)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1687)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1503)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:1187)
```

There is no problem if these two apps running on **Android 9 (API 28)** device. What is changed on **Android 10 (API 29)** regarding access thru `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` and `ContentResolver.openInputStream` to an `uri` from third party apps!?

"Sender" app has

```
compileSdkVersion 30
targetSdkVersion 30
```

"Receiver" app has

```
compileSdkVersion 29
targetSdkVersion 29
```

and `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in the `Manifest`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION` should be added when "Sender" sends `intent` on **Android 10 (API 29)** but the reason why it isn't needed for **Android 9 (API 28)** is unclear.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);        
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); 
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
String mimeType = AppUtils.getFileMimeType(uri, context);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg");
if (intent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null)
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open with"));
```